# Why Toast appears more times than I need?

Tags: android, android-toast, preferencescreen, android-sharedpreferences, checkboxpreference

The problem is that a Toast appears as many times as you open Settings activity, while I need it only once after each click on CheckBox.

Thanks in advance to everyone, who tried to improve my code.

**More detailed description of how the code works:**

- I go to Settings activity and check a box
- Toast appears once
- I return to previous activity using Back button, do nothing, return to Settings activity once more and check a box.
- Toast appears twice
- I return to previous activity using Back button, do nothing, return to Settings activity once more and check a box.
- Toast appears three times
- And so on

  ```
  public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_screen);
      Context context = getApplicationContext();
      SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences settings, String key) {
      Toast mToast;
      mToast = Toast.makeText(this, "toast text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      if(key.equals("checkbox_key")){
          mToast.show();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `settings.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` in your `onPause()` method when you leave the Activity. And I suggest to call `settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` in your `onResume() callback` rather than `onCreate()`.